# Sort by columns and only keep the first line until next value in column 1

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, duplicates

I have a file with roughly 10m lines. Each line is most likely unique, but I'm sorting the file by column 1 then 2 then 3.

```
Column 1 = CODE
Column 2 = DATE
Column 3 = AMOUNT
```

I only want to keep the first line until the next date and so on. Below is an example of what I have and what I need the output to be.

```
Original:  
COL1   COL2         COL3  
ABA    2019-01-01   100  
ABA    2019-01-01   111  
ABA    2019-01-02   140  
ABA    2019-01-02   150  
ABA    2019-01-03   200  
ABA    2019-01-03   220  

Ouptut needed:  
COL1   COL2         COL3  
ABA    2019-01-01   100  
ABA    2019-01-02   140  
ABA    2019-01-03   200
```

Anyone able to help me.  Have tried

`a.drop_duplicates(subset[data.columns[0],data.columns[1],data.columns[2]], keep='first')`

Comment: What is `a`?  What was wrong with what you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is almost correct. This version is a modified version:

```
>> a.drop_duplicates(subset = [a.columns[0],a.columns[1]], keep='first')
```

That produces:

```
    COL1    COL2        COL3
0   ABA     2019-01-01  100
2   ABA     2019-01-02  140
4   ABA     2019-01-03  200
```

Explaining the modifications:

1. *subset* is a named parameter, as you can see on the documentation of [drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html);
2. if column 3 can vary, it shouldn't be present on the subset parameter. The duplicate should consider the first 2 columns;
3. the names you used in the code are not consistent, naming a and data for apparently the same object;

Answer (score 2):

try groupby and then first:

```
a.groupby([data.columns[0],data.columns[1]], as_index=False).first()
```